# Initializing a separate SQLite DB does not work

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi, peewee

I have a Raspberry Pi that records GPS data into an SQLite database. The Pi is randomly turned off and on (power off/on). Whenever the Pi starts up, it starts recording and should create a new database for each day that it runs.

Here is an excerpt form the script:

```
from peewee import SqliteDatabase

db = SqliteDatabase(None)

def init_db():
    db_name = str(date.today()) + '-gps_data.sqlite'
    db_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), db_name)

    db.init(db_path)
    db.connect()

    db.create_tables([GPSRecord], safe=True)
```

Mysteriously, whenever I check the Pi for the stored data, it always uses the first database it created. I.e., if no previous DB exists, it will create one on January 1. Then it's shut down and on January 2 is supposed to create a new DB. However, it reuses the old one and stores data in it. It's as if the connection to the DB survived the restart and kept using the previously created DB.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the return value of `date.today()`? Did you add real-time clock hardware to your Pi?

Comment: The type is `datetime.date` but when `str()` is called it turns it into e.g. `2017-09-24`. No, there is no real-time hardware clock.

Comment: How are you starting the GPS recording script? Does this happen before the Pi gets the time from the network?

Comment: @CL.There is no network connection when the Pi starts. The script is started as a systemd service. The time doesn't need to be accurate (just accurate in days, I suppose) and fake-hwclock should take care of not resetting the time on each boot to 1970. And even if that happened, I'd see the date set to those old dates but when the DB is first created, it uses a correct date.